# How to count the contents by awk?

Tags: mysql, unix, awk, count

I have a file like this, as follows:

```
2017-08-25 03:39:09 20005   login   0
2017-08-25 03:45:59 20005   logout  410
2017-08-25 03:46:42 10007   login   0
2017-08-25 03:46:58 20005   logout  469
2017-08-25 03:46:58 20005   logout  469
2017-08-25 03:47:28 20005   logout  499
2017-08-25 03:50:41 20007   login   0
2017-08-25 03:51:55 20007   logout  74
2017-08-25 03:54:55 20007   logout  74
```

Is it possible to use `awk` to count up like this:

```
2017-08-25 03:39:09 20005   login   0
2017-08-25 03:45:59 20005   logout  410
2017-08-25 03:46:42 10007   login   0
2017-08-25 03:50:41 20007   login   0
2017-08-25 03:51:55 20007   logout  74
```

Comment: What do you mean? Ignoring followup logout lines?

Comment: yes,i want to count the number column avg by ignoring the repeat logout line.

Comment: Avg of what? Example not clear.

Comment: Why are all lines with 469 removed? And what about 499? Seems unique as well. What is "repeat"?

Comment: because log server is wrong.the logout log is repeat.so the first logout line is available after the login line(2000x column is a userid).tks!

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: i want to count user avg online time by the fourth column(410,74...)

Comment: What are you counting? It looks more like you're just printing the value from your logfile.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs  
Yes, I want to get this print first, and then I'll import it to mysql for statistics

Comment: I don't see any counting, you're just removing some lines from your input based on some unspecified criteria. [edit] your question to clarify what it is you're really trying to do (move anything relevant from your comments into your question) and if it does involve counting something than state where and what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/logout/ {if (a[$3]++) next}
/login/{delete a[$3]}
{print}
```

Use this with:

```
awk -f tst.awk input.txt
```

or, use a oneliner:

```
awk '/logout/{if (a[$3]++) next} /login/{delete a[$3]} {print}' input.txt
```

which gives you:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
2017-08-25 03:39:09 20005   login   0
2017-08-25 03:45:59 20005   logout  410
2017-08-25 03:46:42 10007   login   0
2017-08-25 03:50:41 20007   login   0
2017-08-25 03:51:55 20007   logout  74
```

Answer (score 1):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '($4=="login" && !($3 in a)) || ($4=="logout" && a[$3]=="login"){ a[$3]=$4; print }' file
```

- `($4=="login" && !($3 in a))` - if user logs in at first, mark it as logged in `a[$3]=$4`
- `$4=="logout" && a[$3]=="login"` - if ***logged*** user do log out action (at first) - mark it as ***logged out*** (without further processing)

The output:

```
2017-08-25 03:39:09 20005   login   0
2017-08-25 03:45:59 20005   logout  410
2017-08-25 03:46:42 10007   login   0
2017-08-25 03:50:41 20007   login   0
2017-08-25 03:51:55 20007   logout  74
```

Comment: Thank you very very much,your way is also ok.